# VBA Code does not recognize certain numbers from table when using Index-Match-Function

Tags: excel, vba, match, multi-index

I have a table of values, which are factors of a long calculation that follows after in my VBA - Code. In order for me to extract the correct value, I've used the index-match function in my code.

However, I have had to play a little with the code in order for me to be able to interpolate between values.

The code works fine unless my RoundUp values are 0.3 or 0.8, negative as well as positiv.

When psi_up = 0.3 there is an Error 1004 even though it is in the table.

When psi_down = 0.3 there is no issue and the index-match function does not cause problems. Same goes for alpha_up = -0.3 and -0.8

This is the code I have used and the table I need to extract the values from:

````
Dim alpha_0 As Double
Dim psi As Double

Dim psi_down As Double
Dim psi_up As Double

Dim alpha_down As Double
Dim alpha_up As Double

Dim xp01 As Double
Dim xp02 As Double
Dim xp1 As Double
Dim xp03 As Double
Dim xp04 As Double
Dim xp2 As Double

Dim C1_0 As Double


```
    If MyA = 0 And MyB = 0 Then
    psi = 0
    Else
    psi = MyA / MyB
    End If
               

    If My0 >= Abs(MyB) Then
    alpha_0 = MyB / My0
    Else
    alpha_0 = My0 / MyB
    End If
       

    'Parameter to Interpolate 
    
    alpha_down = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(alpha_0, 1)
    psi_down = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(psi, 1)
                                
    alpha_up = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(alpha_0, 1)
    psi_up = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(psi, 1)
    
                            
    If psi_up = 1 Then
    psi_down = 0.9
    End If

    If psi = 1 Then
    psi_down = 0.9
    End If
                            
    If psi_down = psi_up Then
    psi_up = psi_down + 0.1
    End If
                            
    If alpha_0 = -1 Then
    alpha_down = -0.9
    End If

    If alpha_down = alpha_up Then
    alpha_up = alpha_down - 0.1
    End If
    
    If alpha_0 = -0 Then
    alpha_0 = 0
    End If
                                            
                                            
' My0 = 0



    If My0 = 0 Then
                                            
    xp01 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:T71"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_0, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:I71"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
                                
    xp02 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:T71"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_0, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:I71"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_up, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
                                            
                                
    C1_0 = xp01 + (xp02 - xp01) * ((psi - psi_down) / (psi_up - psi_down))
    
    
    
                                                                                     

'If My0 >= abs(MyB)
                                            
    ElseIf My0 >= Abs(MyB) Then
                                                                 
                                
    xp01 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T61"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:I61"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
                               
    xp02 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T61"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:I61"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_up, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
    
                                            
                                
    xp1 = xp01 + (xp02 - xp01) * ((psi - psi_down) / (psi_up - psi_down))
                                            
                                            
    xp03 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T61"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_up, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:I61"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
                                            
                               
    xp04 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T61"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_up, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:I61"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_up, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
                                            
                                            
    xp2 = xp03 + (xp04 - xp03) * ((psi - psi_down) / (psi_up - psi_down))
                                            
                                            
                                            
    C1_0 = xp1 + (xp2 - xp1) * ((Abs(alpha_0) - Abs(alpha_down)) / ((Abs(alpha_up) - Abs(alpha_down))))
                                
                                
                                
                                            
' abs(MyB) > My0
                                                                                  
                                            
    ElseIf My0 < Abs(MyB) Then

                                            
    xp01 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:T71"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:I71"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
                                
    xp02 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:T71"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:I71"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_up, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
                                            
                                
    xp1 = xp01 + (xp02 - xp01) * ((psi - psi_down) / (psi_up - psi_down))
                                            
                                          
    xp03 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:T71"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_up, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:I71"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
                                            
    xp04 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:T71"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_up, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I61:I71"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_up, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
                                            
                                            
    xp2 = xp03 + (xp04 - xp03) * ((psi - psi_down) / (psi_up - psi_down))
                                            
                                            
    C1_0 = xp1 + (xp2 - xp1) * ((Abs(alpha_0) - Abs(alpha_down)) / ((Abs(alpha_up) - Abs(alpha_down))))
                        
    Else
               

End If
````

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA5MW.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu8AO.png)

Thank you so much for reading this and maybe helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your ranges are incorrect for the search of the row, assuming your top right cell is in I50, the the whole Array table including axis goes from I50:T71, your row axis goes from I50:I71 and you column axis goes from I50:T50.

So your index index function should go like this:

```
xp01 = _
    WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T71"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(alpha_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:I71"), 0), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(psi_down, Sheets("C1,0 & C2,0").Range("I50:T50"), 0))
```

Comment: Unfortunately the Range has be set that way, because otherwise I would have two values for alpha. The weird thing is, that the code works fine unless my psi_up = 0.3 or psi_up = 0.8 as well as alpha_up = -0.3 or alpha_up = -0.8

Comment: Show your real excel table showing.line and column names, because obviously you can have the negative and positive numbers in the ranges you are using

Comment: I Just managed to solve it thank you :) Turns out, when I set "psi_up = psi_down + 0.1", for some values it turned out to say "psi_up= 0.3" (for example), yet it was not recognized as such. I pasted the values from VBA into my worksheet and tried using the index-match-function  with the pasted values and it couldn't match. However when I wrote directly into the cells the index-match function worked. So now I defined the variables without adding or subtracting 0.1. Thank you very much for the help though!